# "Cannot resolve symbol 'design' " error on Android Studio

Tags: android

Using these three lines:

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.Toolbar;
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'design'.

How do I solve this problem? Are there any files that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the library in your `Gradle` app's file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

[There is a link to help you include librarys in your project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `com.android.support:design` library, following [the instructions for adding artifacts from the Support Library to your project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with `support-v4` library, when in Android Studio I had this issue, but everything worked fine in command line

For me nothing of below worked:
1. File - Invalidate Caches / Restart...
2. Aligning support versions with compile version

The only thing helped me is:
1. Close project
2. Remove all Andoroid Studio related files: `.gradle`, `*.iml`, `.idea`
3. Import project again

Answer (score 0):

Try to this ..
add below dependecy into app level gradle file ..

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```